# Populate SELECT element in MVC 4 with DataRow elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I have an app that is querying the database and getting a `DataTable`. I need to create a `<select>` in my View whose `<option>` elements rely on the `DataRow` elements in the `DataTable`. My question is, is there a way to use the HTML Helpers to build this kind of `<select>`? If so, how? I'm not very familliar with the HTML helpers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. First of all, put your `DataTable` into a `SelectList`. Put that `SelectList` in your model class, along with a property that will correspond to the user selection (Let's call it `CarId`).

This is what your model would look like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public SelectList Cars { get; set; }
    public int CarId { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use the `DropDownListFor` HTML Helper method in your view, like so (the below assumes Razor):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarId, Model.Cars)
```

Comment: What if I don't have a model? I'm only using a ViewBag. Plus, I don't understand the purpose of CarId. Thank you!

Comment: You can put it in the ViewBag fine, but you'll need somewhere to keep the selected value, that `CarId` will hold the value of the selected item in the dropdown when the form is posted :)

Answer (score 0):

The helpers you are looking for are these

```
@Html.DropDownList
@Html.DropDownListFor
```

The easiest way I have found to use them is with an enumerable select list

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DDLItems { get; set; }
```

I usually fill that in from entity, but you already have a datatable.
How are you getting that datatable? Can you change it?

```
DDLItems = new SelectList(context.Table.ToList(),"ValueColumn","TextColumn",Model.Property);
```

If you can do that, then on your view you can do this

```
@Html.DropDOwnListFor(model => model.Property, DDLList)
```